# Missing keywords error on initializing a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have a Source model and ArticlesController. When user clicks scrape button, the control is passed to below mentioned `ArticlesController#Scrape`. The scrape then calls Source model where the sources are being initialised and the list of articles are returned in a form of hash to `articles` inside `Scrape`.
Source Model -

```
class Source
    attr_accessor :source_name, :source_url, :source_type, :source_key, :tag_name

    def self.all_instances
      @@array
    end

    # Default constructor
    def initialize

    end

    def initialize(source_name:, source_url:, source_type:, source_key:, tag_name:)
        @source_name = source_name
        @source_url = source_url
        @source_type = source_type
        @source_key = source_key
        @tag_name = tag_name
        @@array << self
    end
    def init

        self.new('The Age',
                 'http://www.theage.com.au/rssheadlines/victoria/article/rss.xml',
                 'RSS',
                 '',
                 'Victoria News')
    end

    def import
        init()
        //returns hash of articles back
    end
end 

class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def scrape
        @get_Articles = Source.new
        articles = @get_Articles.import
        //stores articles in article model
        //redirect to article path
    end
end
```

I am getting ArgumentError in `ArticlesController#scrape` on `@get_Articles = Source.new`

Inside Source class the constructor `def initialize(source_name:, source_url:, source_type:, source_key:, tag_name:)` is being called. To rectify the issue I created a default constructor also, so that the parameterized constructor doesn't get called. However, I am not sure how to fix this problem. Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong with the `def initialize` method. You don't want parameterized constructor just removed it.
if you want this as well then you need to handle this for null values also.
Just creating a default constructor will not solve the issue because it will be override with other one.

You can try like this

```
def initialize(options ={})
  @source_name = options[:source_name] if options[:source_name].present?
  #handle and assign other keys and values similer to this
  @@array << self
end
```

now you can use this as

```
@get_Articles = Source.new
```

or

```
@get_Articles = Source.new(source_name: "abc")
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the way you are trying to overload initialize method is incorrect. In ruby if you define the same method again in same class then the most latest interpretation will take preceding(based on when it get interpreted). So here initialize with parameter taking preceding.

There are many ways to overload a method based on parameters

**Approach one**: define method with default value assignment like below

```
 def initialize(source_name = nil, source_url = nil, source_type = nil, source_key= nil, tag_name = nil) 

 end
```

In this approach the sequence of arguments does matter when invoking. i.e we can not invoke method with only tag_name the other values should also be passed as some value or nil

```
like  Source.new nil, nil, nil, nil, 'tag_name_value'
```

**Approach two:** Using Hash as arguments (mentioned by @Prakash): This is the most popular and generic. In this we need to explicitly check for required argument name and need to assign default values to them if needed. This is mostly done by hash merging

```
def initialize(options ={})
  options = {source_name: nil, source_url: nil, source_type: nil, source_key: nil, tag_name: nil}.merge(options)

end

  # calling method   
  Source.new source_name: 'somevalue' #or so one
```

The disadvantage of this approach is there can be many keys in hash passed to method and to handle that you need to do extra check on input hash

```
  Source.new source_name: 'somevalue', unexpected_key: 'unexpectedvalue'
```

**Approach three**
Ruby 2.0 has introduced the keyword arguments (also named argument in ruby 1.9) where you can provide a name to parameters like you were trying, the only thing you should keep in mind is to assign a default value to every parameter.

```
    def initialize(source_name: nil, source_url: nil, source_type: nil, source_key: nil, tag_name: nil) 

    end
```

now you can invoke like

```
Source.new 
Source.new source_url: 'somevalue'
Source.new source_name: 'somevalue'
Source.new source_type: 'somevalue', source_name: 'somevalue'
Source.new tag_name: 'somevalue'
# or any combination of arguments in any sequence 
# but not the following, this give you error 'unknown keyword: unexpected_key'
Source.new tag_name: 'somevalue', unexpected_key: 'unexpectedvalue'
```